# How to append input values into HTML elements with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build an input form that will display submitted values in another page using React hooks. I can see the values when console logged and what I'm looking for is how to append them as HTML elements.

The following code is a simplified version of my work.

```js
const DisplayList = ({ inputs }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>page 2 (parent component)</h3>
    <div>{inputs}</div>
  </div>
);

const AddList = () => {
  const onSubmitForm = () => {
    console.log(`
      First name: ${inputs.firstName}
      Last name: ${inputs.lastName}`);
  };

  const { inputs, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = InputForm(onSubmitForm);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>page 1 (child component)</h3>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs.firstName || ""}
          required
        />
        <label>Last Name: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs.lastName || ""}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <DisplayList />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddList;
```

Any help and guide provided are greatly appreciated!

Here's a link to check out full code: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-data-to-another-page-zujwp?file=/InputForm.js)

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are trying to do. For me, DisplayList is the child component of AddList

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, what exactly do you mean by *'different page'*? So far, your `<DisplayList />` is rendered within `<AddList />`. Is it always the case?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - ah, yes. I actually meant another component. But in the project that I'm working on, it's appending on another page. I should've clarified earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passed input as props to second page component like below.

```
DisplayList inputs={inputs} />
```

And
Used it in the component like below.

```
const DisplayList = ({ inputs }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>page 2 (parent component)</h3>
    <div>{inputs.firstName}</div>
    <div>{inputs.lastname}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Awesome! That's what I want to do it. Just one little hiccup - when I type the inputs, the text is appending simultaneously. It was supposed to append after the button is clicked, similar to what is happening in the console.log. Should I use if/else statement or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Didn't get you question, can you paste here what exactly you would like to be printed in page 2 after submit click please.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to explain: In the page 1 component, there's a form where you enter "John" in the first name input and "Smith" in the second name input. When you submit it, a text "John Smith" should appear on page 2 component. The problem is while you're still typing the inputs, the texts in page 2 component are displaying at the same time. The texts should have appeared only after clicking the button. In other words, it should behave like a to-do list and not markdown previewer.

Comment: Okay,  You can achieve this using changes i have done in the below sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-data-to-another-page-9weyk?file=/InputForm.js:1145-1180

Comment: OMG, that's exactly what I meant. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do maybe:

Pass inputs in AddList:

`<DisplayList inputs={inputs} />`

And change DisplayList to:

```
const DisplayList = ({ inputs }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>page 2 (parent component)</h3>
    <div>{JSON.stringify(inputs)}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just gave ***inputs*** object as props for **DisplayList** component and call the properties of *firstName* and *lastName* within ***p*** tags.

```
<DisplayList inputs={inputs} />

const DisplayList = ({ inputs }) => (
 <div>
   <h3>page 2 (parent component)</h3>
   <p>First Name:{inputs.firstName}</p>
   <p>Lastname:{inputs.lastName}</p>
 </div>
```

);